# LDAP | How to programmatically tell whether a search for specific attribute is case sensitive?

Tags: ldap, case-sensitive

Many LDAP attributes are defined case-insensitive for search. For example:

```
userId ATTRIBUTE ::= {
    WITH SYNTAX DirectoryString { 256 }
    EQUALITY MATCHING RULE caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTRINGS MATCHING RULE caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    ID id-userid
}
```

However, this may be changed by the administrator.

How can I determine whether a specific attribute search is case-sensitive? Is there a way to check this programmatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :caseExactMatch:. See [RFC 4515](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515.txt).

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I need... I don't want to change the search type, I just need to know what's defined on the server.

Comment: Well you can read the schema from the server. This is all discussed in the JNDI Tutorial, Hints for LDAP users.

Comment: I see now that the case-sensitivity can be changed only per search, and not permanently, therefore I mark this answer as accepted. Thanks.